# remove all characters up to a certain character

Tags: r, regex, string, list, gsub

I have a column of strings with things like

`"a1.p.e0.l"` and `"k.r.a1.f.t.i0"`

I am trying to delete everything up until the first vowel. So for the first word above, nothing would be deleted. For the second word, "a1.f.t.i0" would get returned.

I am playing around with gsub but I don't know how to get this to delete any vowel from a certain set (I have `v<-c('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')`, so I need to be able to delete all characters that precede one of the strings in this vowel set. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

You can match and delete `^[^aeiou]*`:

```
s <- c("a1.p.e0.l", "k.r.a1.f.t.i0")
sub("^[^aeiou]*", "", s, ignore.case = T)      # ignore.case depends on if you want to match 
                                               # capital vowel
# [1] "a1.p.e0.l" "a1.f.t.i0"
```

with

- `^` matches the beginning of string;
- `[^aeiou]*` matches zero or more non vowel characters;

---

To start with your character set:

```
v <- c('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
s <- c("a1.p.e0.l", "k.r.a1.f.t.i0")

pattern = sprintf("^[^%s]*", paste(v, collapse = ''))
sub(pattern, "", s, ignore.case = T)
# [1] "a1.p.e0.l" "a1.f.t.i0"
```

Comment: it may be worth clarifying that 's' in `sprintf("^[^%s]*", paste(v, collapse = ''))` is not the same as the variable `s` defined above.  Rather, it is the conversion specification '%s' for `sprintf()`. see `?sprintf`.